# AutoLayout: Issue with scaling UIImageView in UIStackView/UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UIStackView` with views stacked vertically. I have set `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` as the `UITableView`'s row height and estimated height. One of the subviews of the `UIStackView` contains two `UIImageViews` like this:

[image]

The little one is `avatarImageView` and the bigger is `messageImageView`. Here are the constraints:

`avatarImageView`:

[image]

`messageImageView`:

[image]

Then, I'm trying in `cellForRowAt`'s delegate method to update the height of the `messageImageView` to match the image scale (and I let a width of 200px for the image view).

```
let ratio = image.size.width / image.size.height
cell.messageImageViewHeightConstraint?.constant = 200 * ratio
```

I'm trying to use this image for example:

[image]

But it doesn't work at all, the image takes too much space instead and for some reason the avatar image view ends up being hidden (the cell is surrounded in red, above it is a cell with only text that works fine) :

[image]

So what am I missing here?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ratio` is inverted compared to how you are using it:

The easiest fix is to divide by the `ratio` instead of multiplying by it:

```
let ratio = image.size.width / image.size.height
cell.messageImageViewHeightConstraint?.constant = 200 / ratio
```

or if you prefer, change the `ratio` calculation:

```
let ratio = image.size.height / image.size.width
cell.messageImageViewHeightConstraint?.constant = 200 * ratio
```

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you!